# effective UI design and positioning for android

Tags: android, user-interface

I've been working for a while on a rather complex Android application, which involves a lot of layouts and almost all of them are quite complex. However, I am taking a very long time since it is so annoying to position the elements of each layout, since they're not positioned like the dialog editor I'm used to in Visual Studio:

Everything in Android is literally relative to other elements and moving one element usually moves a lot of other elements, plus I can't position anything properly unless I guess the position more or less and move the element several times by guessing the margin on a certain direction.

So my question is, is there a more effective way to design UIs quickly and professionally, so that I don't have to design in such a sluggish way (as I believe it is)? I already tried several editors but they all seem to be very similar to Eclipse's. Is there a more effective way at all?

Also a side note, I'm using a RelativeLayout on each of my layouts

Comment: Something I thought of that should solve my problem, although in a not-so-intuitively way, is to directly edit the XMLs and use the margins to position each element. At least that way I have absolute positions and should be able to be much faster whilst editing each layout (especially since I have to edit these layouts for all screen sizes). I don't know how good an answer this is but it might interest someone else.

Comment: Alternatively, editing the XML directly rather than using the editor is still an option. You can position some things directly, but if there are some elements that seem to be incorrectly positioned on some devices you can simply make them relative to another element. The major difference here is that at least you have control of how each element is relative to each other rather than let the editor do that for you.

Comment: Thea real problem from your question seems to be that you don't quite like the relative positioning that exists in the Android world. If this is the case you should reconsider as this is the Android way. I don't use the editor that much, I just drop the elements that I'll be using and then tweak the xml layout to position the widgets.

Comment: If anything I don't like how when I try to position an element either it gets positioned in specific locations it decides to position (and then I have to Margin it), or it breaks the rest of the layout simply because I moved the element a little to the left and everything that was connected to it moves to the corner or something like that. That's why I'm at least going to decide what is relative to what else since otherwise everything breaks.

Comment: It doesn't "decide" to position itself, in all cases the parent view group determines how views should position themselves. The key to coding complex layouts is to understand how each view group works and use ALL of the available mechanisms. E.g. understanding baseline alignments can significantly improve how you build complex layouts.  Android (and it's development environments) are very different to Visual Studio and desktop apps. You are coding for unknown resolutions in portrait or landscape. You can also of course extend view groups to precisely position things as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do not compare visual studio with IDE of android. It has some limitations.Try to use **android studio** which will help you more in UI design. We can do UI perfectly in android. Relative layout is the best to position the views but should use wisely. Atleast please ellaborate what type of design you want to implement. Atleast provide a sample Image of the design which you want to create. Then only I can tell what you need to do.